# Preliminary question on editing Grid.php in Adminhtml

Tags: grid, magento-1.4, list-view

I have attached a screenshot of a typical backend interface.  I have three ideas of things I want to do, with the first one being the most important:

1. turn the values into the price field into form inputs instead, along with a button at the bottom to "Update Prices" - this is the thing we do the most and it's cumbersome to do this one by one.
2. add a class to rows based on products that are in a certain status, i.e. have not been updated recently, are missing options, etc.
3. Add a column that is not easily calculable just by an SQL query - basically a column that is not a data field column but instead can invoke a callback function.

As I said, #1 is priority.

The issue is, the grid methods are buried so deep in core I don't know where to start on this.  ANY suggestions or help or would be appreciated.

[image: sample grid table with prices shown]

Comment: I would recommend that you start by creating a grid from scratch. There a lot of Tuts in the Web, try looking for magento grid tutorial. Finnaly you need to create a module/extension with rewrites or/and observers to get the work done. But most of it becomes clear when you build from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you will need to override some of core blocks.

You would want to add some magento render function to achieve your requirement.

**I am not sure which grid you are trying to override, but my guess is `product grid manager`. You can have a look Atwix website and get some idea.**

## Example only

```
class Module_NameSpace_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Inline
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Input
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $html = parent::render($row);
 
        $html .= '<button onclick="updateField(this, '. $row->getId() .'); return false">' . Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Update') . '</button>';
 
        return $html;
    }
 
}

$this->addColumn('title', array(
    'header'           => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Title'),
    'align'            => 'center',
    'renderer'         => 'modulename/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_renderer_inline',
    'index'            => 'title',
));
```

**Added renderer property**

There are still few more step to do. Since I don't know exact files to override, I will be just copying and pasting from Atwix's website.

This is not complete answer but should guide you to the right direction.

[Look everything described by Atwix here](http://www.atwix.com/magento/inline-editing-in-magento-backend-grids/)